# Create style that extends from default style set in application theme

Tags: android, android-theme, material-design

I have set the default button style in my application theme, so that it is applied to every button in the app.
There are few buttons that need to have their text capitalized in addition to default style. So what I'm trying to do is something like this
(the following code snippet doesn't work as I cannot set `parent="?attr/materialButtonStyle"`):

```
<style name="capitalizedButton" parent="?attr/materialButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```

Is it possible to extend a style defined in theme.xml? I don't want to refer to the local style that I'm setting in theme as that can change later, instead I intend to access it using theme attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the capitalization happens in addition to your custom default button style, there is no need to make the capitalization style a child of `?attr/materialButtonStyle` (This cannot be done anyhow, as `?attr` references an attribute in the currently applied theme). You can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#ResourcesFromXml).

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/DefaultButton</item>
</style>

<style name="DefaultButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="AllCapsButton">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```

**layout.xml**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:theme="@style/AllCapsButton"/>
```

In the code above, `button` gets the `DefaultButton` style (white text) applied by the theme, and the `AllCapsButton` style (capitalized text) applied in the layout file.

Comment: That's awesome, didn't know custom style is applied over default style. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the question as well. It was fun to research.`?attr` isn't the easiest concept to grasp.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly pass style to `Button` widget in you XML like:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="capitalizedButton"/>
```

Hope you get the answer. If not please explain your question.

Comment: Well my question is how I can extend from theme styles. I cannot set `parent="?attr/materialButtonStyle"` while creating theme. I want to know if there's another way to achieve that.